# datagrid current cell value to textbox

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid with one column and I am trying to get the value of the current cell.
if I use the code below , the textbox value will be 
System.Data.DataRowView and not the value of the cell.
any idea what is wrong?

```
    private void dgOrgcode_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        textBox1.Text = dgOrgcode.SelectedItem.ToString();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried getting the value you need from the objects in the DataGrid instead?

If you have 'Orgcode' objects with a Code property, you can do it like this:

```
private void dgOrgcode_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    textBox1.Text = (dgOrgcode.SelectedItem as Orgcode).Code.ToString();
}
```

Comment: well, I don't know how to use objects!
can you list some tutorials on that